# Strange request url in Angular.js when using $resource's DELETE call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, url

I've been using $resource in AngularJS for a while now and have never encountered this problem, or have any idea where it's coming from.

Essentially, when I use Service.save or Service.get (where Service is the $resource factory), my request url looks perfectly fine.

For example, something like this would be normal:
http://localhost:88888/App/api/group/1/subgroup/1

However, when I've tried to implement the DELETE call, my request url will look something like this:
http://localhost:88888/api/group/subgroup?GroupId=2&SubgroupId=10

This is how my factory looks like:

```
factories.factory("Service", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/group/:id/subgroup/:subgroupid", { id: '@GroupId', subgroupid: '@SubgroupId' }, {
        update: { method: "PUT" },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE' }
    });
});
```

Because the request url is really strange I get a 404 error as would be expected. Does anyone know why Angular is making the request url look like that?

Comment: Hi Daniel - did you ever solve this?